# Javascript. Two arrays, same size, drastically different performance. Why?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

## Method 1

```
const { performance } = require('perf_hooks');
performance.mark('A');

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  let x = new Array(1000);
  x.fill(new Array(1000).fill(0));
}

performance.mark('B');
performance.measure('A to B', 'A', 'B');
const measure = performance.getEntriesByName('A to B')[0];
console.log(measure.duration); // 5.5ms
```

## Method 2

```
performance.mark('C');

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  let x = new Array(1000000);
  x.fill(0);
}

performance.mark('D');
performance.measure('C to D', 'C', 'D');
const measure2 = performance.getEntriesByName('C to D')[0];
console.log(measure2.duration); // 594ms
```

Method 1 is a million size array, but evenly distributed. To retrieve / store, i would treat this as content-addressable storage via some elementary hash to put and retrieve elements.  **5.5ms** for hundred million elements

Method 2 is a straight million size array. It is two orders of magnitude higher to initialize! **594ms** for hundred million elements.

Can someone help explain whats going on here and shed some light on ideal array sizes / array configurations? I imagine this has to do with some kind of optimizations under the hood in v8/C++ land.

Comment: Ah, the old by-reference mistake..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let x = new Array(1000);
x.fill(new Array(1000).fill(0));
```

That is two arrays. `x` is an array with 1000 references to *one* array that's filled with 1000 zeroes.

Total number of elements: 2000 (length of `x` is 1000 + the array it refers to has the length of 1000).

```
let x = new Array(1000000);
x.fill(0);
```

This is one array with million zeroes.

Total number of elements: 1000000.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I see that i made a by reference error instead of by value! I made a small adjustment for what it's worth. for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  let x = new Array(1000);
  for (var j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
    x[j] = new Array(1000).fill(0);
  }
} which  does have better performance, consistently, by 150ms over the straight million sized array. Thanks!